# Unable to use the WebDriverWait in my Selenium Script written in JavaScript in Jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

Previous to my post [see the logs and selenium script written using javascript in Jmeter](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/44241/44327). I want to use the WebDriverWait in my script i.e. written in javascript and I have tried a lot but always get an error and the errors I have recieved at var wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 10) :

`2020-04-13 15:25:42,689 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: TypeError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait is not a function in <eval> at line number 6 2020-04-13 15:25:42,690 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: TypeError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait is not a function in <eval> at line number 6 2020-04-13 15:25:44,002 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: TypeError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait is not a function in <eval> at line number 6`

**Can anyone please help me how can I achieve this using JavaScript in my selenium Script ?**

Answer (score 1):

You were given the code in the previous answer which demonstrates the usage of the [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) class, to wit:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
var wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 10)
var conditions = org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
wait.until(conditions.elementToBeClickable(org.openqa.selenium.By.linkText('More information...')))
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Here is the evidence of its work:

[image]

If you cannot use it for some reason most probably your WebDriver Sampler plugin installation is broken somewhere somehow, the easiest workaround would be:

1. Install clean [latest stable JMeter version](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)
2. Install latest [Selenium/WebDriver Support](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

   [image]
3. Execute the above script. It should be successful
4. Integrate the above solution into your own script.

Comment: Okay !! Thank you, I will definitely check it again by tomorrow and will update my selenium/Webdriver also.